# The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized in NopCommerce

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, plugins, nopcommerce

I have implemnted plugin in Nopcommerce 3.30.
That plugin's controller action method contains:

```
System.Net.HttpWebRequest objRequest = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(idiUrl);
        objRequest.Method = "GET";
        objRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        objRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        objRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        objRequest.KeepAlive = false;
        objRequest.Timeout = 300000;
```

After this line,

```
System.Net.HttpWebResponse objResponse = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)objRequest.GetResponse()
```

I get error i.e.,

> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
>   The details for the log entry.
>
> Full message:  System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

Help me please to solve this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What is idiUrl. Does it work if you visit the URL directly in browser? I think it requires authentication / authorization, and you did not provide that since you are using *DefaultCredentials*.

Comment: Is it something you had to log in to?  Like it works in the browser because you have the correct cookie but otherwise you would have to log in?

Comment: As suggested by AndyMcKenna, please try launching an incognito browser session and visit the URL again. :)